# iOS 4 and Landscape Orientation Lock for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

iOS 4 allows you to lock your iPhone in portrait mode by double clicking the Home button, swiping the dock left, and clicking on the lock icon.

However, it does not appear to allow you to lock the iPhone in landscape mode, which can be desirable for some applications.  Instead, the lock always seems to force portrait orientation.

How can I prevent my iPhone from rotating out of Landscape mode?

Answer (score 7):

Orientation lock on iPhone with iOS 4 only does portrait lock at the moment. Hopefully they will have landscape lock on the next update.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using AssistiveTouch.

In settings, general, accessibility you can setup AssistiveTouch to be enabled/disabled whenever you triple click the home button. Enabling it gives you a global button with accessibility features, including screen rotation.

The process is:

- go into the app you want to use in landscape (this won't work on the home screen, or any portrait only app).
- lock the orientation to portrait
- enable AssistiveTouch (triple click home button if you have that set up)
- tap the AssistiveTouch button, then Device, Rotation, Left (or Right)
- disable AssistiveTouch with another triple click

It will stay in landscape until you remove the orientation lock or use a portrait only app (including the home screen).